# Оценка трудоемкости алгоритма c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Имеется такое задание(скриншот), я написал две функции для бинарного и простого возведения в степень, но я НЕ понимаю как сделать подсчет итераций/оценку трудоемкости.

Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long pow(long c, long d) 
{
    if (d == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (d % 2 == 0)
    {
        return pow(c * c, d / 2);
    }
    return c * pow(c, d - 1);
}
int binpow(int a, int n) 
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n % 2 == 1)
    {
        return binpow(a, n - 1) * a;
    }
    else
    {
        int b = binpow(a, n / 2);
        return b * b;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    long c, d;
    int a, n;
    cin >> c >> d;
    cin >> a >> n;
    cout << binpow(a, n);
    cout << pow(c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Само задание]

Comment: Добавьте глобальную переменную для числа итераций, перед вызовом функции обнулите, в функции увеличивайте...

Comment: если степень кратна двум - это добавляет 1, если не, это две операции. Поэтому, для степеней двойки это будет просто двоичный логарифм, для самого худшего варианта 0xFF....FF это будет по две операции на каждый бит, то есть, 2*log2(N)., что все равно равно log(N).

Comment: нет, мы же не знаем [с++].

Comment: Функция для простого возведения в степень не получилась. Не получилось сделать простое возведение.

Comment: Полагаю вы скопировали код с просторов интернета, но не понимаете что он делает. Вряд ли вам помогут в такой ситуации.